# Ubuntu starting mysql/mysql server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to restart my mysql/mysqld service on my ubuntu server but I keep getting the same errors.
I'm using mysql version: 8.0.23
Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

systemctl status mysql.service output:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-03-27 17:15:22 UTC; 10s ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
    Process: 125121 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 125175 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 125175 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"

Mar 27 17:13:41 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 27 17:13:41 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 27 17:13:41 server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Mar 27 17:13:41 server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Mar 27 17:15:22 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 27 17:15:22 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 27 17:15:22 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

journalctl -xe output:

```
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 26786 and the job result is failed.
Mar 27 17:15:39 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=52 TOS>
Mar 27 17:15:57 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=52 TOS>
Mar 27 17:16:19 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=48 TOS>
Mar 27 17:16:38 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=52 TOS>
Mar 27 17:16:57 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=52 TOS>
Mar 27 17:17:01 server CRON[125231]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 27 17:17:01 server CRON[125232]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 27 17:17:01 server CRON[125231]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 27 17:17:16 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=48 TOS>
Mar 27 17:17:24 server sshd[125236]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Mar 27 17:17:37 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=48 TOS>
Mar 27 17:17:56 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=52 TOS>
Mar 27 17:18:03 server sshd[125237]: Unable to negotiate with 68.183.4.74 port 49612: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellm>
Mar 27 17:18:17 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=40 TOS=>
Mar 27 17:18:30 server systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit fwupd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Mar 27 17:18:35 server hv_kvp_daemon[125265]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dns_info: not found
Mar 27 17:18:35 server hv_kvp_daemon[125267]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dhcp_info: not found
Mar 27 17:18:35 server hv_kvp_daemon[125275]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dns_info: not found
Mar 27 17:18:35 server hv_kvp_daemon[125277]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dhcp_info: not found
Mar 27 17:18:39 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=48 TOS>
Mar 27 17:18:59 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=52 TOS>
Mar 27 17:19:17 server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=MACADDRESS SRC=SRCADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP LEN=52 TOS>
```

Edit 1: new systemctl status mysql.service output

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-03-27 18:20:26 UTC; 28s ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
    Process: 135987 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 136026 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 136026 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 17 (File exists)

Mar 27 18:20:24 emkes-vps systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Mar 27 18:20:26 emkes-vps systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 27 18:20:26 emkes-vps systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 27 18:20:26 emkes-vps systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

journalctl -xe output:

```
Mar 27 18:22:21 emkes-vps hv_kvp_daemon[136366]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dns_info: not found
Mar 27 18:22:21 emkes-vps hv_kvp_daemon[136368]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dhcp_info: not found
Mar 27 18:22:21 emkes-vps hv_kvp_daemon[136376]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dns_info: not found
Mar 27 18:22:21 emkes-vps hv_kvp_daemon[136378]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dhcp_info: not found
```

Comment: Does if work when you disable you firewall?  (`sudo ufw disable`)

Comment: @Luuk no, this still gave me an error

Comment: "an error" is a pretty vague statement....

Comment: @Luuk added new snippets of output

Comment: please have a look at `/var/log/mysql/error.log` (or similar) and share